# How to exclude input of all digits in bash script? I want only letters to work, not numbers and signs

Tags: bash

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n $1 ]]
then
  if [[ -n $2 ]]
  then
    echo "Error: you entered too many parameters"
  else
    regular="^[-+]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$"
    if [[ $1 =~ $regular ]]
    then
      echo "Error: You did not enter text"
    else
      echo $1
    fi
  fi
else
  echo "No parameters found"
fi
```

Comment: Give some examples. It looks like you want to accept `a1` and `1.2.3.4`.

Comment: It’s not clear what if mix of alphanumeric is valid input. OP ask to exclude “all digits”, but then implies no digit “I want only letters to work”. Is a1 valid input ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    regular="^[a-zA-Z]+$"
    if [[ $1 =~ $regular ]]
    then
        echo $1
    else
        echo "Error: You did not enter text"
    fi
elif [ $# -gt 1 ]
then
    echo "Error: you entered too many parameters"
else
    echo "No parameters found"
fi
```

- `$#` is the number of input, you can check it instead of $1, $2 and so on
- Also, instead of checking the wrong input, you can check the correct input